# How can I drain power from a door lever post and charge an inactive one?

Tags: ben-10-omniverse

I know I need to use "Feedback" to drain one of the posts with levers that control the rings on the door in the "The Galvanic Butterfly Effect" stage but am unsure of how to do this.

Can anyone explain please?
I'm playing on XBOX-360.

Comment: I figured it out after some more playing about.

Approach a charged post and hold right trigger and tap X (blue).
This will drain the charge into Feedback.
Then approach an inactive post and hold right tirgger and tap Y (yellow) to dump the charge into the post.

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after some more playing about.

Approach a charged post and hold right trigger and tap X (blue).
This will drain the charge into Feedback.
Then approach an inactive post and hold right tirgger and tap Y (yellow) to dump the charge into the post.